# Magento2 Sales Order Totals Wrong on Order Email

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email

I'm using `Magento 2.3.4` and have my catalog set up so all the prices include tax, all the emails include tax and all the prices include tax.

The issue is that the order confirmation email doesn't send the subtotal and shipping values with taxes (but send the total and items with taxes). The invoice email and credit memo email display the prices correctly.

I've double checked everything and everything seems ok.

Can someone help me, please?

Regards